# Can't get NaN to be replaced with 0 - tried rapply

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't seem to get Not a Number `NaN` error to be replaced with a `0`. Tried using `rapply` but not working for me.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var first = document.getElementById('firstFieldId'),
        second = document.getElementById('secondFieldId'),
        third = document.getElementById('thirdFieldId'),
        fourth = document.getElementById('fourthFieldId');

    first.onkeyup = function () {
        var value;

        // Get the value and remove the commas
        value = first.value.replace(/,/g, "");

        // Make it a number
        value = parseInt(value, 10);

        // Add one to it
        ++value;

        // Turn it back into a string
        value = String(value);

        // Put it in the other text box, formatted with commas
        second.value = numberWithCommas(value);
    };
    third.onkeyup = function () {
        var value;

        // Get the value and remove the commas
        value = third.value.replace(/,/g, "");

        // Make it a number
        value = parseInt(value, 10);

        // Add one to it
        ++value;

        // Turn it back into a string
        value = String(value);

        // Put it in the other text box, formatted with commas
        fourth.value = numberWithCommas(value);
    };

    function numberWithCommas(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
};
```

Made a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7r5SF/2/ - If you put a number in the first or third field, and then clear it, the second or fourth field will show up as `NaN`... It needs to say `0`!

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
++value;
```

with

```
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value+1
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r5SF/22/)

Comment: @verrucktfuchs Sorry, had `isNan` instead of `isNaN`. Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r5SF/22/).